# How to parse json file to DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have some json data of phone accelerometer data. Which looks like this:

```
{u'timestamps': {u'1524771017235': [[u'x',
                                     u'y',
                                     u'z',
                                     u'rotationX',
                                     u'rotationY',
                                     u'rotationZ'],
                                    [-0.02, 0, 0.04, 102.65, 68.15, 108.61],
                                    [-0.03, 0.02, 0.02, 102.63, 68.2, 108.5],
                                    [-0.05, 0.01, 0.1, 102.6, 68.25, 108.4],
                                    [-0.02, 0, 0.09, 102.6, 68.25, 108.4],
                                    [-0.01, 0, 0.03, 102.6, 68.25, 108.4]]}}
```

What I want is to have a dataFrame with columns of the name of the data (x, y,z rotationX, rotationY, rotationZ) and the row of each data entry. The timestamp information can be stored elsewhere.

When I used d = pd.read_json('data.json'), this is what I get:

```
timestamps
2018-04-26 19:30:17.235 [[x, y, z, rotationX, rotationY, rotationZ], [...
```

It seems it takes the timestamps as index. And put all the rest in 1 cell.

I dont have much experience with json so the couldn't really make much sense out of the pandas.read_json api. please help.

My current workaround is to manually skip through the first 2 dictionaries. And create a df with the first column as the headers. It works but it is really not ideal...

```
dataDf = pd.DataFrame(data = d['timestamps']['1524771017235'][1:], columns = d['timestamps']['1524771017235'][0])

x   y   z   rotationX   rotationY   rotationZ
0   -0.02   0.00    0.04    102.65  68.15   108.61
1   -0.03   0.02    0.02    102.63  68.20   108.50
2   -0.05   0.01    0.10    102.60  68.25   108.40
```

Thanks

Comment: @cmaher, I replaced the images with codes. Thanks

Comment: "It works but it is really not ideal..." Why not? It seems fine.

Comment: @AmiTavory because the time info (1524771017235 in this case) is different in each file. And with my way, I have to manually choose it for each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to get access to the key of the dictionary `{u'1524771017235': [[u'x', ...` being the value associated to the key `timestamps` of the dictionary `d` associated to your json file. Then try:

```
d['timestamps'].keys()[0]
```

and it should return your `'1524771017235'` value, so to create your `dataDf` just do:

```
dataDf = pd.DataFrame(data = d['timestamps'][d['timestamps'].keys()[0]][1:], 
                      columns = d['timestamps'][d['timestamps'].keys()[0]][0])
```

and you get the same result.

Comment: thank you very much. The keys is exactly what I need.